# Let $G$ be finite abelian group. Determine $n$ such that following sentence is true.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Determine $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that following sentence is true:
Exists finite abelian group and exists $a,b \in G$ such that $\mbox{ord}(a)=6, \mbox{ord}(b)=10, \mbox{ord}(ab)=n$.

I suppose that for example I can take $n=30$. Because $G$ is abelian we have $(ab)^{30} = a^{30}b^{30} = (a^6)^5 (b^{10})^3=e^5e^3=ee=e$. But I'm not sure that $(ab)^k \neq e$ for any $k \le 29$. So I have a lot dubiousness. I will grateful for help.

Comment: If $G= \Bbb Z_{30}$, then $a = 5$ has order $6$ and $b = 9$ has order $10$, but $a + b = 14$ has order $15$.

Comment: @Tomek: Is $n$ is given here? Are you given $|a|=6,~|b|=10$ and you are looking for a finite abelian group such that in it we have $|ab|=n$??

Answer (score 1):

In a finite abelian group, an element of order $i\cdot j$, for two coprime numbers $i, j$, can always be written (uniquely) as the sum of an element of order $i$ and an element of order $j$. If $a \in G$ has order $6$, then that means that $a$ can be written as the sum of one element of order $2$ and one element of order $3$. In the same way $b$ can be written as the sum of one element of order $2$ and one element of order $5$.

The order of $a + b$ is completely determined by whether the order-$2$-components of $a$ and $b$ are the same. If they are, then they will cancel out, and the order of $a + b$ is $15$, since it can be written as the sum of an element of order $3$ and an element of order $5$. If $a$'s and $b$'s order-$2$-components don't cancel, then the resulting element will have order $30$, since it's the sum of elements of order $2$, $3$ and $5$, respectively.

Comment: It might be useful to give an explicit example: $G=\mathbb{Z}_{30} \times \mathbb{Z}_2$, $a=(5,0)$, $b=(6,1)$ $a+b=(11,1)$.

Comment: It is also good to know that for the first part, being abelian is not necessary. One should just change sum to product and require that the two elements commute.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft It's not even necessary for the group to be finite, just that the elements themselves have finite order. I just wanted to be on the safe side when it comes to assumptions, without having to think every single sentence through, that's why I wrote what I wrote.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft: May I ask you to have a look at my attempt below? That would be kind of you doing that. Thanks.